# Copy a row between two tables ignoring missing columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a stored procedure, and I'm looking for a way to copy one row from one table to another, these two tables have a very similar structure, the only difference is that the second table has some missing columns

For example:

```
Table1
A | B | C | D
```

and

```
Table2
A | C | D
```

There is a way to copy between these two tables without writing every single field in the stored procedure? (obviously ignoring the missing columns)

Comment: Don't be lazy, of course you should specify the columns!

Comment: Not without dynamic sql - I second the comment about specifying the columns if it is always Table1 to Table2 (same tables). Explore Redgate SQL Prompt or SQL Complete or something like that which will enumerate columns for you (or script out "Select top 1000 rows" right clicking on table which also enumerates columns)

Comment: well, the tables could change, so I don't know in advance the columns

Comment: The tables could change? As in you're trying to write an abstract data copier? Generally a bad idea; low performance and reliability.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dynamic SQL approach since you mentioned you don't know the table columns in advance as they change. Hope the data types match :)

```
DECLARE @Table1 VARCHAR(500) = 'TableA', @Table2 VARCHAR(500) = 'TableB'
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = SUBSTRING((
    SELECT
        ',[' + C1.COLUMN_NAME + ']' AS [text()]
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
            ON C1.COLUMN_NAME = C2.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE C1.TABLE_NAME = @Table1
        AND C2.TABLE_NAME = @Table2
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 4000)
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT [' + @Table1 + '] (' + @Columns + ') '
    + 'SELECT ' + @Columns + ' FROM [' + @Table2 + ']'
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql
PRINT @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without dynamic SQL (which would be huge overkill for this problem), but in any case you don't want to.

Queries without the column list specified are inherently fragile. The second one of the underlying tables changes, your query is liable to break. Possibly silently, in a way that will write data other than what you're expecting it to save.

So.

1. Write them out longhand. It's safer, more durable code and it's good for the soul ;-)
2. If you're *really* bored of getting the column lists out and they're that huge, get the list from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Copy, paste, add a few commas and you're done with very little typing.